# Creating a vector of sequences

Tags: r

I'm trying to find all the numbers less than the square root of a inputted number.

I've written a function which will do this on entering one number. I have a sequence of numbers that I wish to evaluate the function for.

```
x <- 1:1000
z <- x^2+1
findy <- function(z){
  y <<- seq(1, sqrt(z), 1)
}
n <- length(y)
for (i in 1:n) {
  a[i] <- z[i] - y[i]
}
```

What I want to do is as follows.

Start with a vector `z <- 1:1000`

Create a new vector: `w <- z^2 + 1`
then for each number in this vector evaluate the function above.

Example

```
z <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)
w <- c(2, 5, 10, 17)
```

(this is where it gets tricky to describe the output)

```
y= 1

   1,2

   1,2,3

   1,2,3,4
```

If that makes sense.
Then I would like to be able to pull out certain values of the above array.

If anyone could help then that would be amazing!

Comment: can you post your sample output?

Comment: @Seddon016 Could you explain the logic behind `y` a bit more. I don't fully understand what `w` is good for.

Comment: Yeah sorry, y is what I want the output to be.

I will post a short example. 

Let z=6 then using the formula I get w=37

I then want this 37 to go into my function, findy(37) and then the output for this particular case is a vector y=(1,2,3,4,5,6).

I want to extend this so instead of having z as a single number, I can have an array containing multiple numbers and the program that will evaluate each number in w. Does this make more sense? Sorry for the confusion

Comment: Have you tried 'lapply'? It would be lapply(w, findy)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An option using `sequence` and `split`. The function returns a `list`.

```
f <- function(x) {
  w <- x^2 + 1                  # why do you need this line?
  out <- sequence(sqrt(w))      # same as sequence(x)
  split(out, cumsum(out == 1L))
}

out <- f(1:4)
out
#$`1`
#[1] 1
#
#$`2`
#[1] 1 2
#
#$`3`
#[1] 1 2 3
#
#$`4`
#[1] 1 2 3 4
```

---

To extract the vectors you can use `$` or `[[`

```
out$`1` # output is a vector
[1] 1
```

or

```
out[2:3] # output is a list
#$`2`
#[1] 1 2

#$`3`
#[1] 1 2 3
```

See `help("Extract")` for details.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I think that will help solve my problem. I'm fairly new to R and so haven't come across lists yet. 

Would it be possible to access the elements in this list. As I would like to now try and divie the input value x by each of these elements.

My overall aim is to try and produce factor pairs for a particular number. 

So for example I would do FactorPair(46) and it would out put (1,46) and (2,23)

Comment: @Seddon016 Updated the post. Hope this helps.